# Know when Zookeeper connection is lost in a Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, connection, apache-zookeeper, health-monitoring

Is there a way to check whether zookeeper connection is lost while running Spring boot application ? After some research I came across health indicators from spring boot . But i cant find any article related to checking the health of the zookeeper connection from Spring boot. Or is there a simple,effective way out without using Health indicators ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

springboot has spring-cloud-zookeeper, it has [ZookeeperHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/62c2502025e9daf67d42c47a605d9aff124e7dc3/spring-cloud-zookeeper-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/zookeeper/ZookeeperHealthIndicator.java) . if you use spring-cloud-zookeeper you do not need to care about it. or you can write your own zookeeper health indicator and take it as a reference.